# Find max per group with dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to get the carrier with the max value of flights during the summer months

```
max_flights_all_c<-nycflights13::flights %>%
   group_by(carrier,month)%>%
   filter(month==6 | month==7 | month==8 | month==9)%>%
    summarise(n=n())
```

Now I'm getting;

```
carrier month   n
9E  7   1494
9E  8   1456
9E  9   1540
AA  6   2757
AA  7   2882
AA  8   2856
AA  9   2614
AS  6   60
AS  7   62
AS  8   62
AS  9   60
B6  6   4622
B6  7   4984
```

but want to obtain only the max value of n for month each month.

Comment: `nycflights13::flights %>% filter(month %in% 6:9) %>% count(month, carrier) %>% summarise(n = max(n))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the `summarise` step, we group by 'month' and get the `max` row of 'n' with `slice`.

```
max_flights_all_c <- nycflights13::flights %>%
                          group_by(carrier,month)%>%
                          filter(month %in% 6:9) %>%
                          summarise(n = n()) %>%
                          group_by(month) %>%
                          slice(which.max(n))
```

Comment: I know the question has a dplyr tag but the data.table solution is 2 x shorter and 4 x faster.

Comment: @Henk That could be true,

Comment: @Eduardo - I have added a more readable solution. As in any package, you will have to invest some time to understand how things work. data.table works a lot like SQL. As you can see in Mike H's benchmark, data.table is much, much faster.

Comment: @Henk sure, agreed!

Answer (score 2):

Credit goes to @Henk for an updated `data.table` solution:

```
setDT(nycflights13::flights)[month %between% c(6,9), .N, keyby = .(carrier, month)][, .SD[which.max(N)], month]

   month carrier    n
1:     6      UA 4975
2:     7      UA 5066
3:     8      UA 5124
4:     9      EV 4725
```

The original solution is in the revision history of the answer.

*Microbencmark:* (for anyone who cares)

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(henk=setDT(nycflights13::flights)[month %between% c(6,9), .N, keyby = .(carrier, month)][, .SD[which.max(N)], month],
               akrun=nycflights13::flights %>%
                 group_by(carrier,month)%>%
                 filter(month %in% 6:9) %>%
                 summarise(n = n()) %>%
                 group_by(month) %>%
                 slice(which.max(n)))

Unit: milliseconds
  expr       min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
  henk  5.612305  6.41659  7.416813  6.953205  7.515347  49.38172   100
 akrun 45.529320 47.51715 51.943065 48.882663 49.834458 221.39357   100
```

Comment: `flights[month %between% c(6,9), .N, keyby = .(carrier, month)][, .SD[which.max(N)], month]`

Comment: @Henk that's more clear to me and slightly faster, mind if I update the answer for future readers?